# Make HTML row clickable then show that rows users profile from database, for a table that was created with a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I created an HTML table of users using a while loop to get the tables data from the database (dynamic table),
but I want to make the rows or at least the first cell of the row clickable, and when clicked it opens another page that displays information about the user from the clicked row kinda like a user profile.
the page that displays the information is also dynamic and retrieves data from the database depending on which row was clicked. this my table code

```
<table class="container">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><h1>Name</h1></th>
            <th><h1>Code</h1></th>
            <th><h1>Votes Today</h1></th>
            <th><h1>Total Votes</h1></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","voting");
    if(!$conn)
    die("connection error");
$sql = "SELECT `name`,`code`,`votetoday`,`total` from contestent";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc())
    {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td>" . $row["code"] . "</td><td>" . $row["votetoday"] . "</td><td>".
     $row["total"] . "</td><tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
?>
    
</table>
```

and this is a part of the code for the page that the link should take to. to show the user's information

```
<?php
$sql1 = mysqli_query($result, "SELECT name, code, Age from contestent,images where 
contestent.code = images.cont_id and images.cont_id=3"); 
// the number three in cont_id=3 shoud be a variable with a value depending on which row was clicked from the table.
while($rows1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1))
{
$contName = $rows1 ['name'];
$contAge = $rows1 ['Age'];
$contCode = $rows1 ['code'];
echo "<h3> Name: ". $contName."<br>";
echo "Age: ".$contAge."<br>";
echo "Code: ".$contCode;
}
?>
```

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and looks clunky and out of place when used in new code.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Talking about *dynamic* and PHP is like talking about a river and a rock. At least in today's meanings of *dynamic*. Nor is your table ***dynamic*** nor you showed any JavaScript code in the tries of making it so. Use always PDO **prepared statements**. Also, nowadays, you don't need to mishmash backend code into frontend. Create an API - get your users, update a state, update a **view** element. Add **listeners** to your FE elements, send a **request** towards a backend **route** - get back your user_id **data**. **Asynchronous** requests, AJAX, no refresh.  Dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GET` method for this issue.

The GET method sends the encoded user information appended to the page request. The page and the encoded information are separated by the ? character.

```
http://www.test.com/profile.php?name=Adam&code=25
```

In the `profile.php` page you can get the values,

```
<?php
   if( $_GET["name"] || $_GET["code"] ) {
      echo "Welcome ". $_GET['name']. "<br />";
      echo "Your Code ". $_GET['code'];
      
      exit();
   }
?>
```

So the HTML code segment will be following,

```
<table class="container">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><h1>Name</h1></th>
            <th><h1>Code</h1></th>
            <th><h1>Votes Today</h1></th>
            <th><h1>Total Votes</h1></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","voting");
    if(!$conn)
    die("connection error");
$sql = "SELECT `name`,`code`,`votetoday`,`total` from contestent";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc())
    {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td>" . $row["code"] . "</td><td>" . $row["votetoday"] . "</td><td>".$row["total"] . "</td>
<td><a href='profile.php?name=".$row["name"]."&code=".$row["code"]."'>View Profile</a></td><tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
?>
</table>
```

You can add more `GET` variable as you want.

Comment: thank you Optimus prime, I used your answers and when I click on view profile I get an Error saying ( Warning: Undefined array key "Name" in C:\xampp\htdocs\voting\profile.php on line 2) and the same for array key Code. although on the address bar I get this (http://localhost/voting/profile.php/name=Sami&code=21) please bare with me I'm new to this.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Now it will be fine. The previous generating url is wrong=> localhost/voting/profile.php/name=Sami&code=21 And correct url should be=> localhost/voting/profile.php?name=Sami&code=21

Comment: thanks a lot, Optimus Prime, it works fine now I really appreciate your help.